# How to recorder a video in android with Unity3D and vuforia integration

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am developing an android application which should record a video. This application has Unity3D(5.3.5f1) and Vuforia(5.x) integration.

I looked into several plugins and C# code but the only thing i found it was like video playback but I need record the video.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I am still looking for the right plugin to figure this problem out but I have found some possible alternatives and I would like to share here.  

First most of solutions are related to screen capture and they don't use the camera image as stream. The following plugins does the trick following screenshots way but they have some problems:  
1) Everyplays works well but it put some ads while sharing and it always send your video to its their social media.  
2) AVPro Movie Capture may do a video recording from live camera but it is only available in Windows.

Comment: I haven't tried it out yet but this could be an option https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-video-capturing-for-unity3d-applications